# Forecasting accuracy in one month and hedging

Tags: time-series, hedging, forecasting

I am working on predicting the daily data of a financial time series $[Y(t+1),...Y(t+j)]$ =$f(X_1(t),...X_1(t-i),.....,X_n(t),...X_n(t-i))$ where $Y$ is a commodity price $X_i$ are predictor variables and I used LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory networks) in order to do that...

How to judge if this predictor is adequate to the task of managing hedging operations?

Specifically I am wondering if an accuracy of one month forecast of **39%** is a good one in order to take a decision to buy a forward contract in order to do hedging?

PS : my one step accuracy (one day) is about **92%** but as you know when the forecast horizon is bigger the accuracy goes down!

Comment: In Economics, they have many (confusing) criteria for judging Forecast Accuracy (RMSE, MAE, MASE, Diebold Mariano Test, etc etc). What criterion did you use to come up with your 39% accuracy? How is it calculated.

Comment: I used R^2 as criteria for my forecast accuracy